# How to efficiently feed FAST ESP with gigabytes of data with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, parallel-processing, fast-esp

This will be a tricky question but I will try anyway:
our task is to feed Microsoft FAST ESP with gigabytes of data. The final amount of indexed data is somewhere in the neighborhood of 50-60GB.

FAST has a .NET API but core components are written in Python (processing pipelines to index documents). The challenge is to reliably communicate with the system while feeding it gigabytes of data for indexing.

**The problems that arise with FAST here are:**

> 1. the system is quirky when it is fed too much data at once as it
>    wants to reindex its data during which the system remains unreachable
>    for hours. Unacceptable.
> 2. it is not an option to queue up all data and serially feed one item
>    at a time since this will take too long (several days).
> 3. when an item cannot be be indexed by FAST the client has to re-feed the
>    item. For this to work, the system is supposed to call a callback
>    method to inform the client about the failure. However, whenever the
>    system times out the feeding client is unable to react to the timeout
>    because that callback is never called. Hence the client is starving.
>    Data is in the queue but cannot be passed along to the system. The
>    queue collapses. Data is lost. You get the idea.

**Notes:**

> 1. feeding an item can take seconds for a small item and up to 5-8
>    hours for a single large item.
> 2. the items being indexed are both binary and text based.
> 3. the goal is for the full indexing to take "only" 48-72h, i.e. it
>    must happen over the weekend.
> 4. **The FAST document processing pipelines (Python code) here have
>    around 30 stages each. There are a total of 27 pipelines as of this
>    writing.**

**In summary:**

> The major challenge is to feed the system with items, big and small,
> at just the right speed (not too fast because it might collapse or run
> into memory issues; not too slow because this will take too long),
> simultaneously, in a parallel manner like asynchronously running threads. In
> my opinion there has to be an algorithm that decides when to feed
> what items and how many at once. Parallel programming comes to mind.
>
> There could also be multiple "queues" where each queue (process) is dedicated to
> certain-sized items which are loaded in a queue and then fed one by one (in worker threads).

I am curious if anyone has ever done anything like this, or how how you would go about a problem like this.

> **EDIT: Again, I am not looking to "fix" FAST ESP or improve its inner
> workings. The challenge is to effectively use it!**

Comment: How many "large items" do you have? Seems like all other issues aside that could prevent you from hitting your 72-hour mark.

Comment: You are going to have to provide something for us to work with.  At this point it would be extremely hard to answer your question since we have no context.  You need to provide more information be as detailed as you can be.

Comment: Currently, it's hard to tell, whether your problems come from bugs in the 3rd party product or from something else. Data loss etc. sound like bugs in this product. Maybe a non-technical approach would be to request those bugs to be fixed.

Comment: Get a backup of the dababase and rewrite it in something sensible. :)

Comment: As @Tom said - 60GB of data that takes 7 days to process is kind of absurd.

Comment: @everybody: I will do more research and double-check my numbers.

Comment: @everybody: I can tell you now that the indexing product is Mircosoft's FAST ESP. We are working with Microsoft but the problem is so deeply rooted I am doubtful that there is a workable solution in sight for the internal memory issues and other limitations of the FAST system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're working with a set of issues more than a specific C# feeding speed issue.

A few questions up front - is this 60gb data to be consumed every weekend or is it an initial backfill of the system ?  Does the data exist as items on the filesystem local to the ESP install or elseware ?  Is this a single internal ESP deployment or a solution you're looking to replicate in multiple places ?  Single node install or multiple (or rather ... how many - single node cap is 20 docprocs) ?

ESP performance is usually limited by number of documents to be handled more than the number of files.  Assuming your data ranges between email size 35k data and filesystem size 350k data you 60gb equates to between 180k docs and 1.8mil docs, so to feed that over 48hrs you need to feed between 3750 and 37500 documents per hour.  Not a very high target on modern hardware (if you installed this on a VM ... well... all bets are off, it'd be better off on a laptop).

For feeding you have a choice between faster coding & more control with either managing the batches fed yourself or using the DocumentFeeder framework in the api which abstracts a lot of the batch logic.  If you're just going for 37.5k docs/hr I'd save the overhead and just use DocumentFeeder - though take care in its config params.  Document feeder will allow you to treat your content on a per document basis instead of creating the batches yourself, it will also allow for some measure of automatically retrying based on config.  General target should be for a max of 50mb content per batch or 100 docs, whichever comes first.  Larger docs should be sent in smaller batches... so if you have a 50mb file, it should ideally be sent by itself, etc.  You'd actually lose the control of the batches formed by document feeder... so the logic there is kinda a best effort on the part of your code.

Use the callbacks to monitor how well the content is making it into the system.  Set limits on how many documents have been fed that you haven't received the final callbacks for yet.  Target should be for X batches to be submitted at any given time -or- Y Mb, pause at either cutoff.  X should be about 20 + # of document processors, Y should be in the area of 500-1000Mb.  With document feeder it's just a pass/fail per doc, with the traditional system it's more detailed.  Only wait for the 'secured' callback ... that tells you it's been processed & will be indexed... waiting for it to be searchable is pointless.

Set some limits on your content... in general ESP will break down with very large files, there's a hard limit at 2gb since it's still 32bit procs, but in reality anything over 50mb should only have the metadata fed in.  Also... avoid feeding log data, it'll crush the internal structures, killing perf if not erroring out.  Things can be done in the pipeline to modify what's searchable to ease the pain of some log data.

Also need to make sure your index is configured to well, at least 6 partitions with a focus on keeping the lower order ones fairly empty.  Hard to go into the details of that one without knowing more about the deployment.  The pipeline config can have a big impact as well... no document should ever take 5-8 hours.  Make sure to replace any searchexport or htmlexport stages being used with custom instances with a sane timeout (30-60 sec) - default is no timeout.

Last point... odds are that no matter how your feeding is configured, the pipeline will error out on some documents.  You'll need to be prepared to either accept that or refeed just the metadata (there are other options, but kinda outside the scope here).

good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to get back to you. This is a single ndoe install. I have yet to find out the exact number of documents, but your gerenal approach to this problem is fantastic. I suppose you have real-world experience with this? :) Thank again for this.

Comment: Hi, no worries about the delay... I'm not exactly quick to reply myself.  Yeah, plenty of real-world... worked for Fast pre-MS, and work with it as my daily job.  If it's just about getting the files in (no external metadata) might want to see if you're licensed for the filetraverser; best feeder fast ever produced (ironically written in python) but handles all the batching & retries like a champ.  With a single node install things are a bit easier to handle... if it's a one time push of 60Gb, even simpler (vs 60Gb/week). When it works well, fast/esp is great... but can get tripped up easily.

Comment: Hi, somehow stackoverflow does not inform me of new comments, but anyway. Right now we are using a component that is hand written in C# to slow down the dataflow to the document dispatcher/docproc because the documents come in so fast that the index gets shut down (as far as i understand it needs to reindex the data which takes about 8h). so they slow it down to a maximum #of docs or MB using a bunch of threads. Each threads then waits for an async callback from the FAST API to notify the caller. At this point we are still investigating whether this is actually neccessary. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use the tasks for such problem.
They can be started sync, async, in thread pool etc, and much more cheaper on memory than models with thread-locking.

I think, the [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405.aspx) fits perfectly for your problem.

Algorithm will looks like:

1. Gather a queue with data you need to publish.
2. Start a task (or tasks, if you are risky :) which takes the heavier object from queue.(and the smallest object from other side), and start upload it.
3. Create a method for the end of uploading, which will start new task for new queue item.
4. You can use Cancellation tokens for the timeouts.
5. Every time you can define on what item the system get error.

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind of input I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply use BULK INSERT directly on the database?  If not, I suggest you work with the provider of the third-party product so that together you can formulate a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

**The database as you discribed it is unusable**. You could find some work arround but you will encounter similar big issues in future. ~10gb taking a day to transfer and random reindexing sounds absurd.

My advice would be to either demand your provider get the database in a usable state (fix the bugs) or that they give you a data extract and you make your own databse.